# Who owns my website?

Tags: contract-law, internet, business, domain-name, investment

I started a website on Wix, and then I registered a limited company later.

How does my limited company own my website? I paid for the Wix website and the domain myself with my own money under my own name.

If I was to seek investors how would they know that the company is entitled to ownership of my website and its proceeds? What would stop me from just operating the website as my own thing and not as a part of the company after I raise funding?

Comment: Did you buy the domain with business money or your own? If your business is a sole proprietorship the answer would be both.

Comment: You should be able to see who the domain is registered to on a domain register website

Comment: Sophisticated investors would require that all relevant assets both physical and not are owned by the company before they invested and require that you agree to devote all your efforts in the domain to the company.

Answer (score 6):

> Who owns my website?

YOUR website is owned by YOU.

If you want it to be owned by your company, you need to transfer the ownership. The domain name registrant and the entity to pay Wix need to be the company, not you.

Same applies to any intellectual property that is used for the website functioning and profit generation.

Comment: You can execute an assignment of the copyright to transfer the IPR of the contents to the company. https://www.gov.uk/copyright/license-and-sell-your-copyright